# Matching values between 2 ranges continuously and pasting value in different col, if true

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet with 2 tabs, BOMSheet & POProcess. I want to copy the PO Number from PO Process sheet by looking up the column B values of POProcess sheet (one by one continuously) in column D values of BOM Sheet and if matches then pasting the PO number in column M of the BOM sheet (for all values that are matched). here is the link of the sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MqYn2AjPncx-RvvyTS8Nj0ujpm9Lcd_ORJF9Wqbw6y0/edit?usp=sharing

I tried the code below but it's not working as its checking up the only one value from the PO Process sheet. Please help how to iterate the values from PO process sheet

function UpdateStatus() {

```
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('POProcess'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
var range = ss.getRange('C4'); //assign the range you want to copy
var data = range.getValues();

var range2 = ss.getRange('B8'); //value to look for to be replaced
var data2 = range2.getValues();

var sheet = sss.getSheetByName('BOMSheet');
var range3 = sheet.getRange('A:L');
var values = range3.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  if (values[i][3] == data2) {
   values[i][12] = data;

  }
}
range3.setValues(values);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function for only PO number.

```
function UpdateStatus() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pSheet = ss.getSheetByName('POProcess'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
  var pNumber = pSheet.getRange('C4').getValue(); //assign the range you want to copy

  var pRange = pSheet.getRange(8, 2, pSheet.getLastRow()-7, 1); //value to look for to be replaced
  var pData = pRange.getValues().map(function(el) {
    return el[0];
  });

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('BOMSheet');
  var range3 = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range3.getValues();

  values.forEach(function(row) {
    if (row[3] == '') return;
    if (pData.indexOf(row[3]) > -1) {
      row[12] = pNumber;
    }
  });

  range3.setValues(values);
}
```

---

For mapping 'Qty Received' column also, try this.

```
function UpdateStatus() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pSheet = ss.getSheetByName('POProcess'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
  var pNumber = pSheet.getRange('C4').getValue(); //assign the range you want to copy

  var pRange = pSheet.getRange(8, 2, pSheet.getLastRow() - 7, pSheet.getLastColumn()-1); //values to map
  var pData = {};
  pRange.getValues().forEach(function(row) {
    pData[row[0]] = row[6];
  });

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('BOMSheet');
  var range3 = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range3.getValues();

  values.forEach(function(row) {
    if (row[3] == '') return;
    if (typeof pData[row[3]] != 'undefined') {
      row[12] = pNumber;
      row[13] = pData[row[3]];
    }
  });

  range3.setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. It copying the values to entire column 12 in the BOMsheet. I need the PO number for the matching values only not to the entire column

Comment: Doing better but pasting in blank cells as well

Comment: one more time ))

Comment: thank you Rafi, its working perfectly now. thank you again

Comment: ra89fi  In previous code there was only C4 from pSheet was to be copied and pasted in BoM sheet against each item matched. here is another question, if I have range of values H8:H17 in pSheet that need to be maped against each item in Bom sheet N colum. i-e row[13] for above code

Comment: I have changed the above link as per new situation. Would you please shed some light on this new situation. Thank you Rafi

Comment: to clear it up, you want to also map 'Qty Received' from psheet to bom sheet ? i see theres a column 'Qty Received' in bom sheet now

Comment: try 2nd function above

Comment: Thank you very much Rafi. Your script working perfectly. Great! .Thanks again